# Azure IoT Hub/Services with Raspberry pi in python

Tags: python-3

I have been googling how to connect raspberry pi 4(with and without buster) to Azure IoT using the python SDK and found somethings but they are not clear as they should be for a beginner like me who has no idea how to use Azure. Some of them are 2-3 years old may be outdated.

Here are some links I found:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-python

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-python-raspberrypi-connect-transparent-gateway

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-get-started

So please guide me or share links or any doc if you have on this and how to achieve this. I am thinking of starting simple from DHT11 sensor data and storing and Analyising it on IoT hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your observation that the articles become outdated (for many reasons but the key one being that the Azure portal gets showered with new eye candy). The most practical approach for Azure IoT work is to leverage Visual Studio Code which can be a challenge for Raspberry Pi boards. Fortunately, VS Code has many extensions that are kept current for Azure IoT work and the links in the documentation will guide you to the current steps for sending DHT11 readings to Azure Hub using Python.

If there is a specific part in your code that is not working for you please provide the reference and I'll gladly dive in to help you out.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But I am having issues getting started. I know this is not a school but if I have found the start I would have gladly finished it.

This https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python link doesn't state how to use this from raspberry pi.

The telemetry one is for Windows PCs by the looks of docs and the rest of them are archived for more than 2 years so...I just thought if somebody here has any experience regarding this can guide me.

Comment: Understood. Let me look into it assuming that your environment is Raspbian and not Windows IoT Core. Rgds.

Comment: @Lucifer, I completed a basic write-up for you using a simulated device. I will send you the link after I upload the document unless you want it via email. Using DHT11 with Python on RPi with the starter code will be an easy extension for you. Rgds.

Comment: Here is the link to the DRAFT article: https://tinyurl.com/uses98y Comments, criticisms & other feedback welcome. Rgds.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I will try these steps right away and will post if any updates if needed. I just want to ask these steps only regarding the sending of data on to the Azure IoT cloud right? Not to get or see data back at any other device.

Thank you Thank you so much for these steps.

Comment: @Lucifer, the example is limited to sending data to Azure but nothing is sent from Azure to anywhere. Of course, you still have to plug in the readings from your DHT11 sensor into the starter code to get your work to a practical/usable level. My two bits are that you emulate the code as is with your own Azure IoT Hub configuration settings to confirm the connectivity between your setup and Azure. Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I will not be able to try Azure for some time due to some problems. So the in-between time I am going to learn about the AWS IoT :)